# Visual Studio Code and Typescript 2.2 auto import

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.2

In the Typescript 2.2 release blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2/ it is said that the following features are added and a video demo with VSC is provided.

> Adding missing imports
>
> Adding missing properties
>
> Adding forgotten
>
> this. to variables
>
> Removing unused declarations
>
> Implementing abstract members

I've started a project based on Typescript v2.2.2 and I'm suing vscode v1.11.2 but those features are not working. I saw that are some vscode extensions available that can do something similar, but I was looking for something official.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try running in no-extensions mode: `code --disable-extensions`. Some other extensions might be causing the issues.

Comment: @Saravana still not working. I've disabled all extensions

Comment: Which version of TypeScript is active in your workspace? This is listed in the StatusBar under `TypeScript XXX` while in a TypeScript file. You can also run the `TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version` command to see which version is currently active

Comment: @MattBierner version 2.2.2 vscode and workspace